# Como gerar vários inputs dentro de um laço de repetição

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso criar `inputs` baseado na quantidade que o usuário digita.

Por exemplo:

```
var quantidade = 5; \\\usuario digitou

for(int i = 0; i< quantidade; i++){
   //aqui vem os inputs
}
```

Nesse caso eu precisaria também mudar o `name` de cada `input` para depois mandar pelo método `POST` para colocar em um Banco de Dados.

Essa é a lógica que eu encontrei, estou aberto a outras. Segue o enunciado do problema:

1. Página de inserção do nome da turma e quantidade de alunos
2. Página contendo um formulário HTML com os campos:

   - Nome do aluno
   - Nota 1
   - Nota 2
   - Nota 3

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os names serão `A0`, `A1`, `A2` etc....

```js
    
var quantidade = 5;

for(i = 0; i< quantidade; i++){

   var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(0);
   
    var y=x.insertCell(0);
    
    y.innerHTML="<input type=text name=A" + i + ">";
}
```

```html
<form action="pagina_destino" method="post">
<table id="myTable" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) - insere uma nova linha

[insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) - insere um `<td>` com algum conteúdo nele.

**Com javascript e dentro de div**

```js
    var quantidade = 5;
    var conteudo="";
    for(i = 0; i< quantidade; i++){
        conteudo +=('<input type="text" name="A'+i+'"/>');
    };

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=conteudo;
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Com jquery**

```js
var quantidade = 5;
var conteudo="";
     
for(i = 0; i< quantidade; i++){
         
    conteudo +='<input type="text" name="A'+i+'"/><br>';
              
};
          
$('.container').append(conteudo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="container"></div>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Sua solução é ótima e me ajudou, mas teria como criar esses inputs da mesma forma  com uma <div> ao invés de uma tabela?

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Olha, não acho que minha resposta vá resolver completamente seu problema pois não sou muito avançado com js, porem posso te dar uma ideia de como fazer isso pelo conhecimento que eu tenho:

A primeira imagem é o código e a segunda é o resultado no html.

No js estou primeiro pegando o valor digitado pelo usuário no loop estou selecionando a div que vou adicionar os inputs que no caso é a com id "inputs".
Após isso estou criando um elemento input e adicionando os atributos name e id neles.
Depois dou um append na div fazendo com que seja adicionado os inputs no html.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<form action="pagina_destino" method="post">
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
</form>


var quantidade = 3
for(i = 0; i< quantidade; i++){

var x=document.getElementById('mydiv')

var y = document.createElement("input")
y.setAttribute("name", `input${i}`)
y.setAttribute("type", "text")

x.appendChild(y)
}
```

Comment: A sua solução é boa e funciona. Eu tive uma visão de como fazer, porém não estou conseguindo executar a função sem a criação de um botão. No meu caso, é preciso que a função seja executada automaticamente. Quando o usuário entrar na página, os inputs já tem que estar criados. Ou seja, ele digitará a quantidade em uma página e depois será redirecionado para outra, com os inputs criados.

Comment: Tentei responder sua duvida do comentario a baixo ali em cima, da uma olhada e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Acabei utilizando **PHP** mesmo, mas as duas respostas me ajudaram muito em outra parte do programa em que eu preciso nessariamente construir por **Javascript**, muito obrigado!.

Segue o trecho do código da solução:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate name="frmCadastroDeTurma" method="POST" action="inserirNotas.php">
      <?php
            $j = 0; $a = 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['qtdAlunos']; $i++){
        ?>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="Nome da Turma">Nome do Aluno</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" value="" required name="<?php echo "nomeAluno" . $i; ?>">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Nome do Aluno é requirido.
            </div>
            <label class="tituloAluno" ><?php echo "ALUNO    " . $a++;?></label>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
            <label for="Primeira Nota">Primeira Nota</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"  placeholder="" value="" required name="<?php echo "primeiraNota" . $j++; ?>">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Primeira nota é requirida.
            </div>
            <hr class="hrInputs" >
            <label for="Segunda Nota">Segunda Nota</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"  placeholder="" value="" required name="<?php echo "segundaNota" . $j++; ?>">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Segunda Nota é requirida.
            </div>
            <hr class="hrInputs">
            <label for="Terceira Nota">Terceira Nota</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"  placeholder="" value="" required name="<?php echo "terceiraNota" . $j++; ?>">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Terceira nota é requirida.
            </div>
            <hr class="hrInputs">
          </div>

        </div>
        <hr class="hrDivisor">
        <?php 
            }
        ?>


        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>

      </form>
```

Utilizei o Bootstrap e o Jquery para a estilização.

Comment: Beleza, apenas uma dica,  nas próximas perguntas, se quiser aceitar respostas com outras linguagens/tecnologias, inclua as tags correspondentes na pergunta para sinalizar que aceita respostas com as mesmas!

Comment: Seu código vai gerar vários elementos (hrs, labels) com mesmo `id`. Acredito que não vai fazer diferença porém isso não está na constituição!!!

Comment: Eu tinha colocado a tag de PHP mas a pergunta foi editada por outra pessoa.

Comment: Sobre os ids, eu consegui mudar o "tituloAluno" para class, mas os outros ids se repetem porque eu ainda não mexi no css do Boostrap para alterar as classes.

Comment: Mas obrigado por lembrar! Era algo que eu já tinha esquecido.

Comment: Vou editar o código aqui e colocar corretamente.